# JOptionPane or better solution

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, loops, joptionpane

I would ask something about my project.
I have a Java program that connects to a website through a Connection class that takes as parameter an int. This class has only a method that return an ArrayList (it gets informations from a web page , and puts results in an arraylist).

In the Main I have a for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<insertUserNumber; i++){}
```

Inside this loop I invoke a Connection object that gets as parameter the "i" of loop and when the object returns the ArrayList, I take it, do something with it and show the result inside a JOptionPane.

The problem is that ONLY when i click on OK i see the other JOptionPane with the result of operation did in the loop. I wish to see them at the same time so I could see all data.

From Javadoc

> All dialogs are modal. Each showXxxDialog method blocks the caller until the user's interaction is complete.

So how can I resolve the problem?

1)Is using multithreading a good solution or there are better ones ?

2) is there a way where I can refresh automatically data of the JoptionPane without start the program?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way where I can refresh automatically data of the JoptionPane without start the program?

Certainly.  Show a `JPanel` in it that uses a `CardLayout`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005).

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

For which concern the first part of the question:

you can't show multiple JDialog if you use showXXXDialog method, because they are modal.
On the other hand if you create a JDialog object you can show it as much as you want:

```
JDialog first = new JDialog();
first.setSize(new Dimension(80,80));
JDialog second = new JDialog();
second.setSize(new Dimension(80,80));

first.setVisible(true);
second.setVisible(true);
```

For what concern changing dynamically the data displayed inside the dialog, yes it's also possible. The first parameter of all showXXXDialog methods is a frame (thus can be a JDialog object too). You can do something like:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
JPanel p = new JPanel ();
p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JLabel label = new JLabel("FOO");
p.add(label);
dialog.add(p);

JOptionPane.showXXXDialog(dialog,....);
```

If you change the content of JLabel label everywhere else inside your program, your dialog will be automatically updated.

Comment: In this way i dont have to click OK to see the other "window" right?

Comment: No, you don't have. But I'm not sure what you are trying to do is a good thing. Having several opened dialog can confuse the user. Anyway if that's what you want I think you can try to play around a bit with this solution.

Comment: The problem is when users want compare the data. How i could do it without show several opened dialog? I wish show only 1 with both datas but i dont have idea how do it.By the way if you want suggest something i will be happy. Thanks